# Leap motion - Processing - Swipe Gesture direction?

Tags: java, processing, gesture, leap-motion

I have been using 2 libraries up til now for my leap motion project as a bodge because they both allowed different functions, unique (better implemented) to each other. However I would like to just use one library as multiple is causing issues.

Basically I am using Leap Motion by Michael Heuer ( I need to use this library because it is currently the only library I can find that allows me to set optimize hmd and also scale factor).

The gesture implementation is as below, is there a way to get the swipe direction from this?

```
void onInit(final Controller controller)
{
  controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_SWIPE);
  // enable top mounted policy
  controller.setPolicyFlags(Controller.PolicyFlag.POLICY_OPTIMIZE_HMD);
}

void onFrame(final Controller controller)
{
  Frame frame = controller.frame();
  for (Gesture gesture : frame.gestures())
  {
      if ("TYPE_SWIPE".equals(gesture.type().toString()) && "STATE_START".equals(gesture.state().toString())) {
    }

    println("gesture " + gesture + " id " + gesture.id() + " type " + gesture.type() + " state " + gesture.state() + " duration " + gesture.duration() + " durationSeconds " + gesture.durationSeconds()); 

 }
}
```

I tried gesture.direction() in the vain hope it might work but direction is not a recognized function.

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance! Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import com.leapmotion.leap.Controller;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Frame;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Gesture;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Hand;
import com.leapmotion.leap.HandList;
import com.leapmotion.leap.processing.LeapMotion;
import com.leapmotion.leap.SwipeGesture;
import com.leapmotion.leap.Vector;

LeapMotion leapMotion;

void setup()
{
  size(16 * 50, 9 * 50);
  background(20);

  leapMotion = new LeapMotion(this);
}

void draw()
{
  fill(20);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
}

void onInit(final Controller controller)
{
  controller.enableGesture(Gesture.Type.TYPE_SWIPE);
  // enable top mounted policy
  //controller.setPolicyFlags(Controller.PolicyFlag.POLICY_OPTIMIZE_HMD);
}

void onFrame(final Controller controller)
{
  Frame frame = controller.frame();
  for (Gesture gesture : frame.gestures())
  {

 if(gesture.type() == Gesture.Type.TYPE_SWIPE) {
    SwipeGesture swipeGesture = new SwipeGesture(gesture);

    Vector swipeVector  = swipeGesture.direction();
    println("swipeVector : " + swipeVector);

    float swipeDirection = swipeVector.getX();
    println(swipeDirection);
   }
}

  HandList hands = frame.hands();
  //println(hands.count());
}
```

Just for future reference, hopefully this can help someone else out!

Comment: Hello, I'm the developer of the [contributed library](https://developer.leapmotion.com/gallery/category/processing). I noted, that there is a demand for the swipe direction naturally. So I will implement and update the library with that feature. After that I will notify you here with a short comment.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use the Leap Motion libraries directly in Processing.

Second, you need to get the gesture object as an instance of SwipeGesture in order to access the direction() function:

```
SwipeGesture swipe = SwipeGesture(gesture);
```

The Gesture base class only defines functions/properties common to all the gestures. That's how it works in the Leap Motion API; it probably works the same way in the wrapper library you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, useful to know I can access the leap motion libraries directly. (I am a little unsure how to do this) I may be being thick but I really cannot work out how to implement it in my code, could you possible help me with integrating it with the code above?

Comment: Sorry ignore my last comment I managed to get it working and get the swipe direction from it however my issue is now that swipe.direction() returns a Vector and when I try to store it in a PVector to grab the x coordinate it obviously does not work and errors saying 'cannot convert Vector to PVector', I tried importing java.utils and storing it in a Vector however when i do this I get 'cannot convert Vector to Vector'

Comment: Again: Ignore above comment, I have now resolved I will post code below, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!